# Linux: Dropbox alternative with sftp/rsync/... access

Tags: linux, rsync, dropbox

Currently on my VPS I'm running couple of sites and Dropbox daemon to store backups. Problem is that VPS has 512M RAM and it was enough until new version of Wordpress (I don't know why, but now it consumes more memory) so I have a really bad choice: either stop Dropbox daemon and  backups or to buy more memory (not that expensive but still). So I'm looking for some way to rsync data into Dropbox or similar service or figure out how to make Dropbox consume less memory.

Any ideas?

**UPD**: For now I've found a way to reduce memory usage. There's a [ruby client for dropbox](https://github.com/tmacedo/ruby-dropbox-sync). It can be run as a daemon, but I'm not using it this way. I've configured my [backup script](http://pastebin.com/1TPT2efc) (dead simple backup solution backing up database and directories to dropbox synced dir) to run its cron.rb script so new backups are uploaded. I didn't do much testing, but on my box I get ~90M RAM used by Dropbox official client and 20-30M used by ruby script. Also note that ruby script is ran only on demand. This is not exactly what I needed, but it solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [git-annex](http://git-annex.branchable.com/). It also has [special remotes](http://git-annex.branchable.com/special_remotes/).

Comment: i'm looking for service. i don't want in house solution

Answer (score 0):

Just use Rsync. Super versatile, Super Fast, SUPER lightweight. Cron jobs can be used to make scheduled backups between one or multiple locations. Cygwin can be used if you need to sync a Windows box too.

I feel your pain, I'm running on a 512 MB VPS myself. I always stick to native Linux utilities when I can.

Comment: and rsync to where? i'm looking for some service with free plans (backups for 3 month are < 1G)